# Is "running a folder" possible in Linux?

Tags: permissions, directory, executable, unix-philosophy

Is there a philosophy behind running a folder as an executable in linux?

```
user@node main % ls -lash ./bin
total 0
0 drwxrwxrwx  2 user  staff    64B May 23 21:04 .
0 drwxr-xr-x  6 user  staff   192B May 23 21:04 ..
user@node main % ./bin         
zsh: permission denied: ./bin
```

Permission denied implies that it may be allowed. If it's not, then why is it `permission denied` rather than something like `can't run a directory`?

Or is it just a weird artifact of the API when directories are involved in this way?

P.S. I am aware that x flag is *adopted* in the directory context to allow/deny cd-ing into them and long-listing (ls -l) them, this is not what this question is about.

P.S.S. In Python, a directory can be treated as a python "executable" if it has a certain file structure inside. (I.e. It's possible to pass a directory instead of a python file to be run by the python interpreter).

Comment: What would you suggest that running a directory would actually do, if it was possible to do so?

Comment: @Kusalananda One of the possibilities - it could work as an abstract entrypoint, when an application is packaged as a collection of files in a folder. Consumers of the application wouldn't need to worry about whether it's a `Make <arg>` or `app-folder/run.sh <arg>`, just do `./app-folder <arg>` and that's it. That's how Python does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running a folder isn’t possible using Linux APIs. In particular, [`execve` returns `EACCES`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#ERRORS) when an attempt is made to do so — this is what Zsh represents as “permission denied”, probably because that error can also be returned if execute permission is denied. The canonical error message for `EACCES` [is “Permission denied”](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html); `execve` uses it to cover a variety of errors, including any attempt to run a file which is not a regular file, which is what is happening here.

Most shells behave like Zsh, but a couple handle this differently; for example, Bash outputs

```
bash: ./bin: Is a directory
```

Zsh can also be instructed to “run” a folder by changing to it, with the `autocd` option (`setopt autocd`). fish always changes to a folder if you try and run it.

Comment: The man page says: "EACCES The file or a script interpreter is _not a regular file_." which might contain a reason for that error code: Even if `execve()` did return EISDIR when trying to execute a directory, it'd still have to have some other error code for pipes and sockets etc. EACCES works as catch-all.

Comment: `fish` also `cd`s into the directories you try to execute like `zsh -o autocd`.  Contrary to `zsh -o autocd`, it doesn't even try to execute them and does it even when non-interactive!

Comment: The behaviour for `bash -c ./fifo` where `fifo` is a fifo seems quite buggy (with 5.0 at least). It seems to try to open it for reading after the execve() fails with EACCESS, and even reads it when it manages, and then only after reports a "permission denied" possible prefixed with "bad interpreter" if a shebang was read.

Comment: The zsh behaviour is the norm among shells in my tests, bash's is rather the exception (and I don't particularly like the fact that it hides the actual error returned by the system)